# Creating an Auto Downloader/Updater getting an error opening the downloaded files

Tags: c#, webclient, download

I'm using c# and creating an auto downloader/updater, that checks to see if the application is there, or if the application needs an update.  If the new version of the app needs to be downloaded it downloads it and puts it in the LocalAppData/MyApplication Directory.

When I try executing the application I get the error

```
The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid
```

I don't understand what this error is coming from.  If I just copy the files over with FTP they work just fine, no matter where I put them.  But as soon as the updater runs..I get that error.

I'm using C# and using the WebClient to download the files, and then using WshShellClass to create shortcuts for the application.

Any insight would be great.  If it would help for me to post the code that I'm using to download the items I can do that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the issue, the WebClient was not downloading the MyApplication.exe.config, because the server returns a 404 not found for config files when just trying to http download them...obviously..sorry folks

Answer (score 0):

Cool question.

Also such error occurs unser following circumstances:
1. load assembly in domain.
2. assembly renames executable config to .backup and creates new config
3. assembly is unloaded and loaded again